# Python does not update dataframe while iterating over rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I don't get why python won't update my dataframe object:
The code snippet is this:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   t = df.loc[index, :"score"]
   b = [float(i) for i in t if i != 's']
   m = sum(b)/len(b)

   df.at[index, "score"] = m

   print(df.at[index, "score"]) # Does not print out m, it prints out 0, the default value
```

The thing that this snippet should do is get all the values in a row, compute the average and then add this average to the dataframe.

Comment: Although I suggested an alternative answer below, I cannot answer directly why this doesnt work. For this, could you a) show a sample dataframe in your question and b) tell me which version of python you are working with?

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over rows in a `DataFrame` is *very* seldomly the way to go. 
Instead, use
`df.loc[:, :'score'].mean('columns')`
which is more readable and much faster.

To answer your question directly (why your way doesn't work) we would need more information (see comments).